# React: Failed to minify the code from this file - because of a change I made

Tags: reactjs

I changed the code in a module and now when I run 'npm run build' I get the above error, altough the code works just fine on my local host! Is there a work around to make it work?

```
value: function render() {
      var _props2 = this.props,
          onPlaceSelected = _props2.onPlaceSelected,
          types = _props2.types,
          componentRestrictions = _props2.componentRestrictions,
          bounds = _props2.bounds,
          rest = _objectWithoutProperties(_props2, ['onPlaceSelected', 'types', 'componentRestrictions', 'bounds']);

      return _react2.default.createElement('input', _extends({
        ref: 'input',
        onChange: (e) => {
              if (!e.target.value) {
                this.props.haveri(null)
              } else {
          let a = e.target.value;
          var options = {
            types: ['(cities)'] //this should work !
         };
```

The error specifies the line with 'onChange: (e) => {', it's a code that I added to manipulate the module.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module code you shared looks like it's already transpiled, so the arrow function might be off there as well as the let inside.

Try changing both, the arrow function for a normal function declaration and the let for a var and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, it did the trick. In addition I had to change the way of passing the props of course, used: changeLink={this.onChangeLinkname.bind(this)}.
Also, I used _props2, which is defined in the render function, instead of this.props.